# How to pass instance of Request from a controller function to another controller function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have to call a function from one controller an other controller.

```
public function getquickviews(Request $request){
     $report = new ReportController();
     $report ->Applications($request->except('cl_e_start_date'));//it's not working its giving me error that it expect and instance of Request and passed array()
}



    public function Applications(Request $request) 
    {
/*APP USAGE*/
     }
```

and I have to pass instance of Request to Application function. But the issue I don't wanted to pass all the parameter from getquickviews Request like if I am getting email,phone,name on the getquickviews function but I only have to pass phone,email to Application function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
$report ->Applications($request->except('cl_e_start_date'));
```

To

```
$report ->Applications($request);
```

Comment: this will pass all the request parameters but I want to only send some of them

Comment: may be you can do this by making a class which implements/extends Illuminate/http/Request to filter data

Answer (score 12):

You need to create a new instance of Request.

```
public function getquickviews(Request $request){
 $report = new ReportController();
 $content = new Request();
 $content->something = $request->something;
 $content->somethingElse = $request->somethingElse;
 $report ->Applications($content);
 }
```

and then you have to recieve it in:

```
public function Applications(Request $request) 
{
/*APP USAGE*/
 }
```

and that's it.
Regards.

Comment: the issue with this in Laravel 7 (as I have only tested it on Laravel 7) is that it returns the whole request object itself. example of a  returned object "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {},
        "id": 1,
        "amount": 20,
        "comment": "deduction"

Answer (score 1):

try as following (not sure it's gonna work) :

```
public function getquickviews(Request $request){
    $returnedRequest = $request; // do whatever with your request here
    return redirect()->route('SecondController.Applications', compact('returnedRequest'));
}



public function Applications(Request $request){
    /*APP USAGE*/
}
```

Comment: this will send all the request parameters but I wanted to send only some paramenters like on the getquickviews I receive 4 but I only wanted to send 3 to Applications function

Comment: `$returnedRequest = $request; // do whatever with your request here` here you do whatever with your first request. So if you want only 3 parameters, set the 3 parameters in `$returnedRequest`

Answer (score 1):

To be able to create a custom request and thus use it to reference a post method in a controller, you need to first initiate an instance of Request as @martin Carrasco has described above:

the code below is a continuation of martin Carrasco

```
public function getquickviews(Request $request){
$report = new ReportController();
$content = new Request
([
     'firstParam' => $request->param1,
     'secondParam' => $request ->param2,
]);

 $report ->Applications($content);
```

}

Try that n hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work :

```
$report ->Applications($request->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to get requests into next method or any next level call.

First you can inject Request class depenednacy into that method for an example:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Form Submits here
}
```

If you want to pass $request into other method for example to display data after insert you can do this way:

```
public function showStore(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->get());
}
```

Then you can call this method from store method

```
$this->showStore($request);
```

or second is you can use request as metho into showStore or any n level call. Like this:

```
public function showStore()
{
    dd(request()->all());
}

$this->showStore(); // You do not require any injection.
```

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the particular key and value you want and delete the rest from the `$request` before passing it to the function. First convert the $request to array by

```
$request->toArray()
```

and then delete the unwanted keys by doing

```
unset($request['key-here']);
```

and then pass it to the function

```
$report ->Applications($request);
```